# Pegar master key android studio para configurar no parse

Tags: android

Estou configurando o servidor Parse no meu projeto. Como nunca tinha mexido com isto, fiz um teste antes numa aplicação de teste e rodou 100%. Fui tentar configurar novamente para meu projeto android e agora ele solicita uma master key.
Alguém sabe aonde pego isso no projeto ?

[image: Configuration Android Studio]

No campo ele mostra que é item opcional, mas se não coloco nada ele dá um erro e volta com a mensagem acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Master Key* (chave mestra) é um mecanismo de segurança. Usando a chave mestra você ignora todos os mecanismos de segurança do seu aplicativo, como [permissões de nível de classe](https://parseplatform.github.io//docs/android/guide/#security-class-level-permissions) e [ACLs](https://parseplatform.github.io//docs/android/guide/#security-object-level-access-control).

> Tendo a chave mestra é como ter acesso root para servidores da sua
>   aplicação. Você deve proteger sua chave principal com o mesmo zelo com
>   que você se proteger senha de root suas máquinas de produção

Você pode gerar uma Master Key, gerando um [ID aleatório com um gerador UUID on-line](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?hl=en&gws_rd=cr&ei=-PPfV_yVNMK1wATutqa4BQ#hl=en&q=uuid%20generator) ou simplesmente fechando os olhos e bater a cabeça no teclado umas 3 vezes que vai funcionar. =)

#### Detalhes

- [Parse Security I - Are you the Key Master?](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/)